# Removing `underfull \hbox` warning with \hbox: how to do it?

Tags: boxes, warnings

How can I remove the warning

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 4 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10
> test

in the following MWE ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\hbox to3cm{test}Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: the latex syntax would not need leavmode or hbox  `\makebox[3cm][l]{test}`

Comment: The TeX syntax would be `\hbox to 3cm{test\hfill}`.

Comment: @campa I voted to undelete yours as it explained why the message happens, I would have said something about that if your answer hadn't been there already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latex syntax for this adds the glue to stop the underful message (and `\leavevmode`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makebox[3cm][l]{test}Hello
\end{document}
```